# Uniform integrability and converging process

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $Y = (Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\mathbb P(\{Y_0=2\})= 1/2=\mathbb P(\{Y_0=0\})$.

We consider the $Y$ adapted process $X = (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ given by $X_n=\prod_{i=1}^nY_i$
Show that there is $X\infty\in L^1(P)$ such that $X_n\to  X_\infty$ almost everywhere, but $X$ does not converge to $X_\infty$ in L1(P) as $n\to\infty$.

I think I have to use the sub martingale theorem here. Am I right? But how can I use $\mathbb P(\{Y_0=2\})= 1/2=\mathbb P(\{Y_0=0\})$ here?
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $X_n$ is be a martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)$, where $\mathcal F_n$ is generated by $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ provided $(Y_n)$ is independent (this is not assumed but it is crucial). It turns out that  by independence,
$$
\mathbb P(X_n\neq 0)=\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{Y_i\neq 0\}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb P\left(Y_i\neq 0\right)=2^{-n}
$$
hence $X_n\to 0=X_\infty$ almost surely. But $\mathbb E[X_n]=1$ hence  the convergence in $\mathbb L^1$ cannot happen.